# Python UPDATE query with parameters in different places

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I'm writing a simple script that checks if user account is about to expire. I'm having a problem with an UPDATE query - it doesn't update, basically. All examples I've found on the internet seem to use tuples to update rows, however my case requires parameters to be apart from each other.

I'm completely new to Python (I started literally yesterday). My database is MySQL (almost all examples on the web use SQLite) and I can't change that. I use Python 3 and the server is running on Ubuntu 18.04. I tried replacing %s with ? or :variable. I also tried insecure way of doing this (SQL Injection vulnerable) and it didn't work either.

This is my current code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import datetime
try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="rootery-root",
        passwd="example",
        database="playground"
        )

    sqlCursor = mydb.cursor()
    sqlCursor.execute("SELECT id, email, last_email_date FROM users WHERE soon_expires = 1")
    sqlResult = sqlCursor.fetchall()
    setLastMailCmd = """UPDATE users SET last_email_date =%s WHERE id =%s"""
    today = datetime.date.today()

    for i in range(0, len(sqlResult)):
        id = sqlResult[i][0]
        email = sqlResult[i][1]
        lastemaildate = sqlResult[i][2]
        daydiff = lastemaildate - today
        setLastMail = sqlCursor.execute(setLastMailCmd, (id, today))
        if daydiff.days >= 30:
            print "Sending mail and updating \"last_email_date\"."
            setLastMail
        else:
            print "%s already received an e-mail this month - ignored." % email
            setLastMail  # debugging purposes

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("SQL connection error.".format(error))

finally:
    if (mydb.is_connected()):
        sqlCursor.close()
        mydb.close()
        print("Disconnected from database.")
        print(today)
```

I expected it to update my table with data provided by the `for` loop, however it does nothing at all.

Comment: This code won't even run. Start with using python3 and proper IDE. What do you think `setLastMail` should do? The way you use it won't work.

Comment: @TomWojcik could you elaborate? I'm using nano currently, it runs using `python program.py` as intended, for the most part.

Comment: If you are using python3 then it should fail with syntax error on print without `()`.

Comment: This line won't do anything. `setLastMail  # debugging purposes`

Comment: @TomWojcik i think he is using python 2

Comment: @min2bro there's a shebang for python3. First time I'm seeing it.

Comment: `setLastMail` should execute the command specified above the `for` loop. Now that I think about it, simply putting `setLastMail` won't do anything - how the hell I missed this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using functions more. You put everything in one place and it's not easy to debug.

Your problem is the way you use `setLastMail  # debugging purposes`. It does nothing.

What would be better:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="rootery-root",
    passwd="example",
    database="playground"
)

sqlCursor = mydb.cursor()

def set_last_email(id):
    stmt = """UPDATE users SET last_email_date =%s WHERE id =%s"""
    today = datetime.date.today()
    sqlCursor.execute(stmt, (id, today))
```

And then just execute your `set_last_email(id)`.

Remember to make cursor global, otherwise it won't be available in your function. Or acquire it directly in your function from global connection.

That's of course a dummy example, but you need to start somewhere :)

Comment: Hmm. I used a function at first and it didn't work out (don't remember why) and decided to just do it "inline". I'll try doing it this way, thanks.

Comment: I solved the problem. I used functions and cleaned up the whole thing a bit, yet `UPDATE` still made no changes at all - the solution was pretty obvious - my `UPDATE` execute only loaded the query into the memory, but to actually make it work I had to add `mydb.commit()` at the end of the script - I figured that committing at each loop iteration wouldn't be a good solution.

Comment: Ahh, I wanted to tell you yesterday to remember about `commit` but I thought it's not necessary, because there's sometimes `autocommit=True` somewhere. Anyway, good job! And you're correct, commit the entire session.